# odoo 15 ldap user not able to login

Tags: ldap, odoo, odoo-15

I created a new ubuntu server and new database, connected it to ldap. After configuring ldap, when i try to login it just takes long time and do nothing not even logs. when I try to login with a normal user it works fine. I tested the connection ldapsearch and every think is ok full admin on LDAP

---

Did anyone face this issue. been trying to fix it for a week.

update 1:

when the connection is correct that issue happens.

update 2:

after long time I am getting an LDAP exception occurred: but without any info

update 3:

when ldap is enabled Login takes long time without any logs

some times meaning ones I got "in order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection"
If I choose create it simply sends login failed without creating the user.

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/34537

Changing LDAP port to 3268 works.